# Campos obrigatórios em sessão com local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, localstorage

Desenvolvi um form com localstorage nesse site [aqui](http://medicalseg.com.br/) porem dentro dele tem dois inputs um para nome e outro para salário porem precisava que esses campos fosse obrigatórios pois quando não são preenchidos e o usuário clica em próximo os campos vão em branco agora se deixar os campos como obrigatórios isso não vai mais acontecer é possível fazer isso segue emu código:

HTML:

```
<div class="indenizometro-box">
                        <img src="img/indenizometro-icon.png" class="icon-indenizometro" alt="Indenisômetro"/>
                        <h2 class="title">Indenizômetro</h2>
                        <div class="box-informations">
                            {{--<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                tempor
                                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>--}}
                            <h4 class="subtitle">Selecione a causa: <i class="fa fa-question-circle"
                                                                       aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </h4>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline indenizometro-list">
                                <li class="list "><a class="link -morte morte" data-tipo="morte">Morte</a></li>
                                <li class="list"><a class="link -invalidez invalidez" data-tipo="invalidez">Invalidez</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        {{--Event morte--}}
                        <div class="box-informations-morte">
                            <h4 class="title">Causa: <span>Morte</span></h4>
                            <p class="subtitle">Insira os dados do paciente</p>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <input type="number" name="idade" class="form-control" id="idade"
                                           min="1" max="10" step="2"
                                           placeholder="Idade"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                                        <input type="phone" name="salario" class="form-control money-mask" id="salario"
                                               placeholder="Salário atual"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                                <li><a class="btn-back-morte">voltar</a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn-next-morte">Próximo</a></li>
                            </ul>


                        </div>

                        <div class="box-protected-morte">
                            {{--<img src="img/info-segurado.png" class="img-responsive img-segurado"/>--}}
                            {{--<div class="result-morte"></div>--}}
                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled result-morte-list">
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="title">idade</h5>
                                    <div class="result-morte-idade" id="idade-morte"></div>
                                </li>
                                <div class="bar-list"></div>
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="title">Salário atual</h5>
                                    <div class="result-morte-salario" id="salario-morte"></div>
                                </li>
                                <div class="bar-list"></div>
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="title" id="causa-morte">causa</h5>
                                    <div class="result-morte-causa"></div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="subtitle">Valor da indenização</p>
                            <h3 class="price" id="price-morte"><span>R$</span>35.000,00</h3>
                            <a class="btn-protected-back-morte">voltar</a>
                            <a href="{!! route('indenizometro') !!}" class="btn-protected-morte">Proteja-se!<br/><span>Avançe para avaliar seu seguro</span></a>
                        </div>
                        {{--End event morte--}}

                        {{--Evend invalidez--}}
                        <div class="box-informations-invalidez">
                            <h4 class="title">Causa: <span>Invalidez</span></h4>
                            <p class="subtitle">Insira os dados do paciente</p>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="idades" class="form-control" id="idade"
                                           placeholder="Idade"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                                        <input type="phone" name="salarios" class="form-control money-mask" id="salario"
                                               placeholder="Salário atual"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                                <li><a class="btn-back-invalidez">voltar</a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn-next-invalidez">Próximo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box-protected-invalidez">
                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled result-invalidez-list">
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="title">idade</h5>
                                    <div class="result-invalidez-idades"></div>
                                </li>
                                <div class="bar-list"></div>
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="title">Salário atual</h5>
                                    <div class="result-invalidez-salarios"></div>
                                </li>
                                <div class="bar-list"></div>
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="title">causa</h5>
                                    <div class="result-invalidez-causas"></div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="subtitle">Valor da indenização</p>
                            <h3 class="price"></h3>

                            <a class="btn-protected-back-invalidez">voltar</a>
                            <a href="{!! route('indenizometro') !!}" class="btn-protected-invalidez">Proteja-se!<br/>
                                <span>Avançe para avaliar seu seguro</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        {{--End Event invalidez--}}
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box-informations-morte").hide();
    $(".box-protected-morte").hide();
    $(".box-informations-invalidez").hide();
    $(".box-protected-invalidez").hide();

    //morte
    $(".-morte").click(function () {
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-morte").fadeToggle('slow');
    });

    $(".btn-next-morte").click(function () {
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-morte").hide();
        $(".box-protected-morte").fadeToggle('slow');
    });
    //end morte

    //invalidez
    $(".-invalidez").click(function () {
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-invalidez").fadeToggle('slow');
    });

    $(".btn-next-invalidez").click(function () {
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-invalidez").hide();
        $(".box-protected-invalidez").fadeToggle('slow');
    });
    //end invalidez


    $(".about").click(function () {
        $(".thumbnail").hide();
        $(".person").fadeToggle('slow');
    });

    //localstorage morte
    $('.morte').on('click', function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('tipo', $(this).attr('data-tipo'));
    });

    $('.btn-next-morte').on('click', function () {
        var idade = $('input[name=idade]').val();
        var salarioAtual = $('input[name=salario]').val();
        sessionStorage.setItem('idade', idade);
        sessionStorage.setItem('salario', salarioAtual);

        var secureValue = (65 - idade) * 12 * (0.7 * salarioAtual) * 1000;
        secureValue = secureValue.formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
        sessionStorage.setItem('seguro', secureValue);

        $('.box-protected-morte .price').html('<span>R$</span>' + secureValue);
        $('.result-morte-idade').append('<p>' + sessionStorage.idade + '</p>');
        $('.result-morte-salario').append('<p>R$' + sessionStorage.salario + '</p>');
        $('.result-morte-causa').append('<p>' + sessionStorage.tipo + ' </p>');
    });

    $('.btn-back-morte').on('click', function () {
        $(".box-informations").fadeToggle('slow');
        $(".box-informations-morte").hide();
    });

    $('.btn-protected-back-morte').on('click', function () {
        $(".box-informations-morte").fadeToggle('slow');
        $(".box-protected-morte").hide();

        $( ".result-morte-idade" ).empty();
        $( ".result-morte-salario" ).empty();
        $( ".result-morte-causa" ).empty();
        $( ".price" ).empty();
    });



    //localstorage morte
    $('.invalidez').on('click', function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('tipo', $(this).attr('data-tipo'));
    });

    $('.btn-next-invalidez').on('click', function () {
        var idade = $('input[name=idades]').val();
        var salarioAtual = $('input[name=salarios]').val();
        sessionStorage.setItem('idade', idade);
        sessionStorage.setItem('salario', salarioAtual);

        var secureValue = (65 - idade) * 12 * salarioAtual * 1000;
        secureValue = secureValue.formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
        sessionStorage.setItem('seguro', secureValue);

        $('.box-protected-invalidez .price').html('<span>R$</span>' + secureValue);
        $('.result-invalidez-idades').append('<p>' + sessionStorage.idade + '</p>');
        $('.result-invalidez-salarios').append('<p>R$' + sessionStorage.salario + '</p>');
        $('.result-invalidez-causas').append('<p>' + sessionStorage.tipo + ' </p>');
    });

    $('.btn-back-invalidez').on('click', function () {
        $(".box-informations").fadeToggle('slow');
        $(".box-informations-invalidez").hide();
    });

    $('.btn-protected-back-invalidez').on('click', function () {
        $(".box-informations-invalidez").fadeToggle('slow');
        $(".box-protected-invalidez").hide();

        $( ".result-invalidez-idades" ).empty();
        $( ".result-invalidez-salarios" ).empty();
        $( ".result-invalidez-causas" ).empty();
        $( ".price" ).empty();
    });
});
```

OBS: para verem o funcionamento da sessão cliquem no link do [site](http://medicalseg.com.br/) que está na pergunta e desçam para sessão indenizometro lá estará o form que preciso que fique com os campos obrigatórios

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi é isso que precisa

```js
  $('.btn-next-morte').on('click', function () {
        var idade = $('input[name=idade]').val();
        var salarioAtual = $('input[name=salario]').val();
        
        if(!idade || !salarioAtual){
           // Lógica para tratamento de erro 
           alert('Mensagem de erro');
           return;
        }
        
        sessionStorage.setItem('idade', idade);
        sessionStorage.setItem('salario', salarioAtual);

        var secureValue = (65 - idade) * 12 * (0.7 * salarioAtual) * 1000;
        secureValue = secureValue.formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
        sessionStorage.setItem('seguro', secureValue);

        $('.box-protected-morte .price').html('<span>R$</span>' + secureValue);
        $('.result-morte-idade').append('<p>' + sessionStorage.idade + '</p>');
        $('.result-morte-salario').append('<p>R$' + sessionStorage.salario + '</p>');
        $('.result-morte-causa').append('<p>' + sessionStorage.tipo + ' </p>');
    });
```